# scanf seg fault in C with char* array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I'm working my way through a book on operating systems, and some of the book's sample code is giving me a runtime segmentation fault. I'm somewhat new to C from Java, and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

The little program here is supposed to generate a simple shell, read a command in and fork a process to execute it. The problem is in the book's code itself, at the "scanf" function call; when I input something at the "osh>" prompt, I get a segmentation fault.

Form what I know about C, I think memory might need to be allocated for the args array, but since it's an array declared directly in the main function, I think I might not need to. I figure that if I did, it would be in the book's code.

Anyway, here's the code that generates the fault:

```
char* args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1]; /* command line (of 80) has max of 40 arguments */

int should_run = 1; 

int i, upper;

while (should_run){   
    printf("osh>");
    fflush(stdout);


scanf("%s", args); /* THIS CAUSES SEGFAULT */

char* localArgs[3];
char* pch;
```

/* ... */

Thanks in advance for the help. Learning memory management in C is quite the journey.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing an array of pointers to `scanf()`, it expects an array of `char`.

An example of how to use [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) correctly to scan a text string would be

```
char string[100];

if (scanf("%99s", string) == 1)
 {
    printf("scanned string: %s\n", string);
 }
else
 {
    printf("error: unexepected error in `scanf()'.\n);
 }
```

Read the link throughly  to understand why I wrote this code like I did, if you do you will start to understand how `scanf()` works, and when you do you will start writing more robust programs, and probably stop using `scanf()` too.

Comment: The compiler should display a warning. Rule #1 : don't ignore C compiler warnings:-)

Comment: @sfk And in fact, enable compiler warnings, make it as annoying as possible, this rule applies to beginners as well as to experienced c programmers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I modified my code to try and use an (allocated) char pointer and pass that to scanf instead, however I still get a segmentation fault after I input the args. Is it possible that other memory problems further down in the code cause an early segfault? Even when I try to printf the value of *args right after the scanf, it fails. I know I've allocated enough space for the string.

Comment: When you do illegal things most of the time the behavior is undefined, so pretty much anything can be the cause, I would recommend a debugger.

Answer (score 3):

```
char* args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1];
```

This is creating an array of size (MAX_LINE/2+1) of char pointers. If you want to use one of these char pointers as string, you must allocate them:

```
args[which_arg] = malloc(arg_max_length*sizeof(char));
```

And to read a text into it:

```
scanf("%s", args[which_arg]);
```